# Dozer map null to modelview class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, dozer

I have a problem . I am using Dozer for mapping data in spring and hiberante but when using mapping , maps null to variables of modelview class.

Please help me.

This is Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("/getTraffic/{id}")
    public List getTrafficByEmpNo(@PathVariable(value = "id") Float empNo){
        return Dozer.mapList(dateFileService.getPersonTraffic(empNo),DataFileViewModel.class);
    }
```

This is Dozer.java

```
public static  <S, D> List<D> mapList(List<S> sourceList, Class<D> destinationClass) {
        List<D> destionationList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (S source : sourceList) {
            if (source != null) {
                destionationList.add(getMapper(destinationClass).map(source, destinationClass));
            }
        }
        return destionationList;
    }

    private static <D> DozerBeanMapper getMapper(Class<D> destinationClass){
        DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        String packaging = destinationClass.getSimpleName();
        if (!packaging.contains("ViewModel")) {
            mapper.setMappingFiles(Arrays.asList("dozer/"+packaging.toLowerCase()+"/"+packaging.toLowerCase()+".xml"));
        } else {
            String classDozer = packaging.substring(0,packaging.indexOf("ViewModel")).toLowerCase();
            mapper.setMappingFiles(Arrays.asList("dozer/"+classDozer+"/"+classDozer+".xml"));
        }
        return mapper;
    }
```

this is dozer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
      http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
    <mapping>
        <class-a>org.sap.model.DataFile</class-a>
        <class-b>org.sap.web.viewModel.DataFile.DataFileViewModel</class-b>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

[image: This is my result]

Comment: Can you post the source for org.sap.model.DataFile and  org.sap.web.viewModel.DataFile?

Comment: Based on the mapping thats posted here, it is leveraging the wildcard mapping functionality of Dozer. Having the source of the two classes being mapped is important in understanding why the mapping is not working as expected.